# update mysql on debian

Tags: linux, debian, mysql

I'm trying to update Mysql on debian without success, and all tutorial on internet just fails.
I got Debian 6.0.6 squeeze, my mysql version is `mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.1.63`.
I did `apt-get update` and `apt-get upgrade` it says that nothing is to upgrade.
So I downloaded the last version `wget --content-disposition http://www.mysql.com/get/Downloads/MySQL-5.5/mysql-5.5.28-debian6.0-x86_64.deb/from/http://cdn.mysql.com/` and installed it

```
# dpkg -i mysql-5.5.28-debian6.0-x86_64.deb 
(Reading database ... 41264 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to replace mysql 5.5.28 (using mysql-5.5.28-debian6.0-x86_64.deb) ...
Unpacking replacement mysql ...
Setting up mysql (5.5.28) ...
```

And... Nothing...

I deleted the previous package `apt-get --purge remove mysql-server` then reinstalled it like above, same message, and nothing was installed.

when I do `mysql -V` I have `version mysql Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.1.63, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 6.1` and when I do `dpkg -l mysql` I get version `5.5.28`... on phpinfo I got `5.1.63`

Is there a step missing to do this installation ?

Thank you very much

Comment: What does `dpkg -l | grep mysql` show you?  I think  you may have upgraded the server package but not the client.  Certainly, running `mysql -V` gives you the client version, not the version of any server.

Comment: ii  mysql                               5.5.28                       MySQL built using CMake

Comment: Ok, then what does `which mysql` tell you?  You may have more than one mysql client on your system, with the older one on the path.  Also, use `dpkg -L mysql` to see where the package has put its mysql client, then run that version explicitly, using the *full* path, to see what version that reports.

Comment: I did the manipulation of sudonano so doing `which mysql` doesn't return anything

Comment: Ah, so you removed all the evidence ;)

Comment: Yes ! but you are right it must be that, now I need to reinstall mysql, I need to see how to do this step

Comment: `sudo apt-get install mysql-server mysql-client` puts me 5.1.63 back....

Comment: If you had those two installed *and* your custom build package, that was probably your problem.

Comment: My problem is that apt-get gives me the old version of mysql, I have no way to tell him "Get me the version 5.5 !"

Comment: Add to the apt sources file a repository which does contain the package you want.  Or install it manually, as you tried already.  But if you install manually, check where it puts the files and run those, not any other older versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I can only recommend you to try
    "sudo apt-cache search mysql"
to find everything related.
    "sudo apt-get purge mysql*"
to remove everything related.
Besides, it's recommended to use aptitude instead of apt, but if you started with apt, keep it.

Comment: I did this, but can't reinstall anything...

Comment: I know some people recommend using aptitude rather than apt.  I think they are wrong.  aptitude is just a front-end to the apt-get suite and has, at times, kept its own cache of metadata about packages quite separately from the main package database.  By all means use aptitude to query the package database but I would advise against using it at the command-line to install or manage packages - apt-get is perfectly good for that.  Do you have any specific reason to recommend against apt-get, or is this just voodoo advice?

Comment: You can see aptitude features here http://wiki.debian.org/Aptitude Well I recommend to use aptitude instead of apt-get because of it's better dependencies handling.